# How to sort a list of 1million records by the first letter of the title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a table with 1 million+ records that contain names. I would like to be able to sort the list by the first letter in the name.

..  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

What is the most efficient way to setup the db table to allow for searching by the first character in the table.name field?

The best idea right now is to add an extra field which stores the first character of the name as an observer, index that field and then sort by that field. Problem is it's no longer necessarily alphabetical.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why only the first letter? How should *"aardvark"* and *"aardwolf"* be sorted? Databases can easily sort the entire text field using lexical order by simply specifying a `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Is it taking an unreasonable amount of time to sort (maybe you're sorting too often)? Do you have a proper index on the name column?

Comment: How would I do an order by the Letter A, where A is the first character in the table.name field?

Comment: Again, why only the first letter‽ That's rather atypical for an *ordering* algorithm. How should two words starting with the same letter be ordered? To literally answer your question, `ORDER BY SUBSTR(name, 0, 1)` should do it (substitute `SUBSTR` to your database's substr functionality, not sure about postgres), but I doubt that's what you really want.

Comment: so lets ignore the first letter part. How can I all records that start with A? All A's no B...z ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You said in a comment:

> so lets ignore the first letter part. How can I all records that start with A? All A's no B...z ? Thanks – AnApprentice Feb 21 at 15:30

I issume you meant `How can I RETURN all records...`

This is the answer:

```
select * from t
where substr(name, 1, 1) = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the questions above as to why you would *want* to do this -- a regular index on the whole field is functionally equivalent.  PostgreSQL (with some new ones in v. 9) has some rather powerful indexing capabilities for special cases which you might want to read about here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-createindex.html